# Play 2.4.6 performance

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using Play 2.4.6, Scala 2.11.8 and Cassandra 2.1.14. Few days back I faced problem where clients were receiving response from play application after 15-20 seconds. I have set up of 2 servers where play application is running, both servers are having 8 cores. I am not sure why play application was responding so slowly. CPU usage are very low around 15%. I am using fork-join pull with following parameters

```
contexts {
  cassandra-pool = {
    fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-factor = 1.0
      parallelism-max = 200
    }
  }
}
```

I am using above pool as ExecutionContext in all of my controllers and all requests are wrapped in Action.async. As I know play supports very high concurrent requests. In my case, I was receiving only 800 requests and I had two servers to serve the requests.

When I tried to hit 1000 concurrent requests, all requests were served in less than 50 milli seconds. I tried this in local environment, with single core system.

I have gone through various blogs and seen that for IO fork join pool should not be choice. I couldn't understand what gone wrong. Can someone please explain what could be issue? How can I conclude that thread-pool was the issue? What "parallelism-max" is meant for? Does it keep upper bound on thread pool count?

Comment: If you want a reliable insight on what happened, you'll need to have some metrics on your application. The best would be to have the execution time of your methods that call external services: databases, webservices ...
It's more likely that the problem came from an external service than from the configuration of the thread-pool.

Comment: Thank you. I have investigated more and created new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330430/request-response-life-cycle-in-playscala-2-4-x. Please see if you can help.. :)